# TFS reports not opening

Tags: reporting-services

I am getting following error while opening TFS reports:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) Query execution failed for dataset 'dsProjectGuid'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Answer (score 0):

It seems the analysis services cube doesn't process well. Log on to the application-tier server and open the Warehouse Control Web Service by entering the following URL in a supported web browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
```

And follow the article below to manually process data warehouse and analysis services cube for Team Foundation Server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237.aspx

If manually processing doesn't work, you can try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console. To delete the Tfs_Analysis database, you can connect to **Analysis Service** using **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, expand the **Databases** node, and delete the Tfs_Analysis database.

To recreate the Tfs_Analysis database, please refer to the following steps:

1. Launch TFS Admin Console>>Application Tier>>Reporting, in the right panel, click **Edit** to open the **Reporting** windows.
2. Under the **Analysis Services** tab, input the Tfs_Analysis under **Database** textbox, and re-provide the required account under **Account for accessing data source**.
3. Click **Ok** to generate the Tfs_Analysis database in **Analysis Services**.
4. Click **Start Jobs** and **Start Rebuild** to rebuild warehouse and the Analysis Services database.

Comment: Will my existing reports will be deleted if I delete the Analysis Db?

Comment: Data associated with builds or work items that have been permanently deleted from the database will be permanently removed from the data warehouse when you rebuild it.
Also, data in the warehouse or cube that originates from third-party sources might also be lost. Even though most third-party tools are capable of republishing data, that capability depends on the individual vendor. Contact your vendor to determine what (if any) data might be lost. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube